# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. Flutter Provider Package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

**homepage.dart**

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();    
_userProfile = Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context,listen: false).userData;
if (_userProfile['isPaid'] == false) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PaymentScreen.routeName);
 }
}
```

**Error**

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

This error is bugging me. Please help me resolve this.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide the your `build` function, that’s where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code as below:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();    
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, (){
  _userProfile = Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context,listen: false).userData;
  if (_userProfile['isPaid'] == false) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PaymentScreen.routeName);
  }
 });
}
```